# { "title": "Validation error", "message": "notNull Violation: User.firstName cannot be null,\nnotNull Violation: User.lastName cannot be null",

Tags: validation, error-handling, null

im getting the following error when I try to signup for a new user for my RestAPI using postman:

{
"title": "Validation error",
"message": "notNull Violation: User.firstName cannot be null,\nnotNull Violation: User.lastName cannot be null",
"errors": {
"firstName": "User.firstName cannot be null",
"lastName": "User.lastName cannot be null"
},

I re visited my user models and ensured the allow null was set to false.

Answer (score 0):

This needs more context. You need to share the request that you are sending to your REST endpoint and also the validation code snippet.

From what you have shared, setting `allowNull` to `false` means that you are not accepting `null` in the request and you seem to be sending `null` values in the request. Try setting `allowNull` to `true` or send valid values in the request body.